# RVM Gemset for gem development

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I'm working on a gem I always end with the confusion about which Gemset to use.

I usually use the gemset of a project where the gem is being used, or create a separate gemset for the gem, and each time I want to work on my gem I do

```
rvm use ruby-3-3-3
rvm gemset use my-gem
```

I do this manually because I've never seen a `.ruby-version` or a `.ruby-gemset` file on a gem source code, neither on the .gitignore file.

But this is tedious, what developers use to define and use a ruby version / gemset when working on a gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add a `.ruby-version` or/and a `.ruby-gemset` file to the gem and ignore them [globally](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) in git, just for that gem. This way you won't have to change the version each time, and you won't have to commit anything in the gem's .gitignore file